# Docker - runing with error (The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found)

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to run my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app in Docker container but getting this kind of error in the Docker log

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
> framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not
> found.
>
> - No frameworks were found. You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The specified framework can be
>   found at:
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64

I am not using `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` in my ASP.Net Core 3.1 project...

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
...
COPY ["OtherLibsProjects"]
...
RUN dotnet restore "Web.App.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "Web.App"
RUN dotnet build "Web.App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.App.dll"]
```

`Web.App.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;618</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**\*.ts" Exclude="$(GlobalExclude)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" Version="4.5.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExpressiveAnnotationsCore.dll" Version="0.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How does `Web.App.csproj` looks like? Also, what is `OtherLibsProjects`?

Comment: Added .csproj file to question. `OtherLibsProjects` - references to library projects in my solution.

Comment: `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is definitely Windows specific API, you can't use it inside linux container

Comment: ok, I'll try to remove it, thnx for the answer.